# Jquery Change() and One() function?

Tags: jquery, addition, onchange

I would really like to know what the following jquery line of code does:

```
$('input', f).add('textarea', f).add('select', f).change(enable).one('blur', function () {

 //commands go here

});
```

Can somebody please explain to me the first line of code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line takes every `input`, `textarea`, and `select` element within some other jQuery object, `f`, and binds a change event handler, which is some function called `enable`.  Then, it hooks up an event to the `onblur` method of those objects that only gets executed at most one time.

The line:

```
$('input', f).add('textarea', f).add('select', f)
```

Is really just equivalent to:

```
$('input, textarea, select', f)
```

Which selects the union of all of those elements within some context, `f`.  Then, check out the documentation for [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for the full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the purpose of all these commands by browsing the [jQuery API online.](http://api.jquery.com/)
[add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
[change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 1):

1. `$('input', f)` - find all `<input/>` elements in the context of `f`
2. `.add('textarea', f).add('select', f)` add additional elements to the first matched set again in the context of `f`
3. `.change(enable)` register a `.change()` handler to all elements in the jQuery object (input, textarea, and select)
4. `.one("blur", function(){} )` bind one blur handler to each of the elements in the jQuery object.